# Improper Deep Copy of Model Instance still affecting the Original Instance

Tags: python, django

I have two models, Movie and Review. Review has a foreign key field related to Movie. I have been trying to make a deep copy of a Movie instance so I can edit the Review objects associated with that instance *without* those edits affecting the original and being saved to the database.

**models.py**

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)


class Review(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**views.py**

```
# Create and save movie object
movie = Movie(title="Nightcrawler")
movie.save()

# Create and save two review objects
review1 = Review(movie=movie, author="John", active=True)
review2 = Review(movie=movie, author="Rob", active=False)
review1.save()
review2.save()

# Create deep copy of movie instance
movie_copy = copy.deepcopy(movie)

print("Original before change: " + movie.title + " has " + str(len(movie.reviews.all())) + " reviews.")

inactive_reviews = movie_copy.reviews.filter(active=True)

print("There are " + str(len(inactive_reviews)) + " inactive reviews.")

# Remove inactive reviews from deep copy
movie_copy.reviews.remove(*inactive_reviews)

print("Deep copy after change: has " + str(len(movie_copy.reviews.all())) + " reviews.")

# Check if original movie instance was altered
print("Original after change has " + str(len(movie.reviews.all())) + " reviews.")
print("Author of the first review is: " + str(movie.reviews.first().author))
```

The output of the views.py code is as follows:

> ```
> Original before change has 2 reviews.
> There are 1 inactive reviews.
> Deep copy after change: has 1 reviews.
> Original after change has 1 reviews.
> ```

I want and expected the original to still have 2 reviews, and the change to only affect the deep copy `movie_copy`. But the original seemed to be affected as well. How can I make it so the removing of inactive replies is only applied to `movie_copy`? To give some context, my goal here is to pass only active reviews into a template for them be displayed without actually deleted inactive reviews from the database. Passing in all reviews and then sorting out the inactive replies in the template is not great in my situation.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: A deep copy will indeed not change that, since it creates a query with the primary key it is assigned, and the deep copy simply has the same primary key, and thus will eventually make the SQL queries.

Comment: You can show only the active reviews with `mymovie.reviews.filter(active=True)`, so you can use this query in the view and thus only pass a subset of the reviews to your template *without* the inactive ones.